# What is the standard way to install an elisp package?

Tags: use-package

I'm interested in trying out the features of the `htmlize.el` package that I read about [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Htmlize). The article does not explain how I can import it into emacs. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I think replacing *import an elisp program* by *installing an emacs package* in the title is perhaps more descriptive.

Comment: @Name Done. I guess my problem was that the documentation didn't make it clear that I could install the package via melpa, though admittedly this could be due to my own ignorance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the package manager to install a package and keep it up to date. `htmlize` isn't in the default archive, but you can easily add new ones (Marmalade and MELPA are the two most popular):

```el
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
```

Once you have the repositories set up, `M-x package-install htmlize` will install the package, `M-x list-packages` will list the available packages (and let you get updates on installed packages).

Comment: I'm making this the new accepted answer as it is what I ended up using. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

People sometimes overemphasize the use of `package.el`, IMO.  Certainly, you can use it to download and install a library.

But you can also just download it (however), put its name in your `load-path`, and then `require` it.  Especially for a one-file library, this is hardly difficult to do.

```el
(add-to-list 'load-path "DIRECTORY WHERE htmlize.el[c] IS")
(require 'htmlize)
```

This is one "standard", and straightforward, way to "import" a library.

Comment: I ended up installing it via Melpa as per @kaushalmodi's comment on ReneFroger's answer. Your answer will undoubtedly be useful for future reference. Thanks!

Comment: MELPA is great - the best of the ELPA repositories (IMHO). Certainly by far the most used and most voluminous.

Comment: -1: Maybe I'm “overemphasizing” package.el, but now that after all these years we finally have a standard way to distribute and install Emacs Lisp packages we should recommend and encourage its use, and not cling to the bad old habits of downloading and copying random Elisp to random places.  Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @lunaryorn: 1) I did not say that you are overemphasizing anything. 2) It's not either-or black-vs-white. The package system is a real asset, and yes, its use should be advertised. It is not the only way to obtain and load libraries, however. And it doesn't hurt some Emacs users to know that.